# errno 10061 no connection could be made because the target actively refused it

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, http-proxy

I have am using the following code to connect to twitter api using proxy. 
the following environment variables are set :
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.domain.com
https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyserver.domain.com

```
              if self.api.proxy_url:
                    proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://%s/' % self.api.proxy_url, 'https': 'https://%s/' % self.api.proxy_url})
                    print('proxy: %s' % proxy)
                    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
                    resp = opener.open(req)
                else:
                    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

note that the user with which I logon is created on another domain. for example when I use browser to open a website it prompts me for username and I login like userdomain\username and password.

I get error message that the host refused connection.

Comment: I had this error too. It means you aren't using the proxy right. Maybe a false password or false username.

Comment: I have given the same user name and password that I give even my browser prompts me. I can connect to twitter on my browser after I input that userdomain\username and password.

Comment: You could try the requests library. Its pretty simple to use it for proxies. Plus the requests library is easier to read, which makes it easier to use.

Comment: Here is a sample:   requests.get(url,
            auth=requests.auth.HTTPProxyAuth(username, password),
            proxies={'http': domain})

Comment: ok.. actually I haven't built this program from scratch. I am using tweepy. will try to see if I can fit it in. will report back.

Comment: got it to work :) i just added port number at the end.. like

Comment: https://username:password@proxyserver.domain.com:80

Comment: Ah good job. Totaly forgot about it.

Comment: that just took me a day to figure out lol.. anyways happy that at least I did figure it out! thanks!

Comment: I said you in the first comment __I had this error too. It means you aren't using the proxy right.__ ;)